# I updated the theme, but now the font-face is not working? Whats going on?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-face

Staging site: https://woocommerce-81222-860870.cloudwaysapps.com/

--

The live site shows the correct cursive font. But on the staging, it is not working. I had to update the theme, and now it does not work. I have the same paths too. Not sure whats going on.

I have tried different varieties of paths.

```
   @font-face {
    font-family: 'quentinregular';
    src: url('font/quentin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('font/quentin-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
   }
```

I don't see any errors for the font face.

[Image of the cursive font face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6moms.jpg)

Comment: I get a "404" error (file not found) for both `https://woocommerce-81222-860870.cloudwaysapps.com/font/quentin-webfont.woff` and `https://woocommerce-81222-860870.cloudwaysapps.com/font/quentin-webfont.woff2`. Incidentally, I also get a 404 error for `https://81222-445514-raikfcquaxqncofqfm.stackpathdns.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/blocks/style.css?ver=3.6.4`.

Comment: Is it an issue with just the staging site since it works on the live site (before the update)? Or are my paths wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do those files exist in those locations?

Comment: https://woocommerce-81222-860870.cloudwaysapps.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/beyoutiful-child/font/quentin-webfont.woff

Thats the file. I changed the path to this, but it still doesn't work on the site.

Comment: It's most likely without the `public_html` part. That looks like part of the server path, but not necessary part of the URL.

Comment: Tried this, but no luck:

@font-face {
    font-family: 'quentinregular';
    src: url('../wp-content/themes/beyoutiful-child/font/quentin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../wp-content/themes/beyoutiful-child/font/quentin-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

Comment: I don't see that file being referenced on your site at all anymore. Try `wp-content/themes/beyoutiful-child/font/quentin-webfont.woff`.

Comment: It seems that the site is now offline...

Comment: I deleted the staging site, and remade it just to see if it would help. It didn't. I don't understand. https://woocommerce-81222-873665.cloudwaysapps.com/

It's weird because on the live site, it the exact same paths and it works. Just doesn't work on this staging site.

Comment: I'm not seeing the "quentin" woff files being requested. [Here's what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLKeV.png).

Comment: Is this a path issue? Server issue? Not sure what to do..

Comment: Where is your `@font-face` defined? Are you sure that file is being loaded?

Comment: It's in the child theme, under a folder "font". Like I said, this issue is so weird to me because all I did was update the theme. And now it's not loading up the font face. Unless its a theme issue, but shouldn't it still find the font-face? Everything is working just fine except this issue.

Comment: What I mean is this: before, at least you were getting a 404 error for the "quentin" woff files. Now, they are not even being requested. What has changed? Where is your `@font-face` code and is that file being loaded?

Comment: Got it. I put the @font-face code in the theme editor instead of the child theme and it worked. It seems that its not reading the child theme css anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The font no longer exists at font/quentin-webfont.woff or font/quentin-webfont.woff2 you will need to locate the new path to the font files. Try searching in the file manager to find the fonts

Answer (score 0):

In your `head` tag, you have a `style` tag that contains the following code:

```
@font-face { font-family:quentin;src:url(//81222-445514-raikfcquaxqncofqfm.stackpathdns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/quentin.woff2) format('woff2'), url(//81222-445514-raikfcquaxqncofqfm.stackpathdns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/quentin.woff) format('woff'), url(//81222-445514-raikfcquaxqncofqfm.stackpathdns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Quentin.ttf) format('truetype');}
```

So, there you have `font-family:quentin;`, but the CSS rules contain `font-family:quentinregular;`. You need to change that.

Comment: I think it was a plugin I was trying. I removed the plugin.